# Force assignment in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

For example I want a function that takes an object of numbers and replaces each number with its stringified value. In JavaScript i could write something like this:

```
function myStringifier(object) {
  for (let key in object) {
    object[key] = object[key].toString();
  }
}

myObject = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};

myStringifier(myObject);
```

But how can I handle this in TypeScript? The following code would produce an error:

```
function myStringifier(object : {[index: string]: number}) : void {
  for (let key in object) {
    object[key] = object[key].toString(); /* ERROR! Object properties are of type number 
    and therefore cannot be assigned any string values to */
  }
}
```

Important note: I`d like to do this **WITHOUT** allocating any additional variables inside the function scope and/or copying the object or reference to it.

**P.S.:** setting the type of the object argument to:

```
{[index: string]: number | string}
```

- is not the way out either. I want to be sure that that the argument passed is an object of numbers.

**P.P.S.:**

Thanks for your answers.

I understand that the requirements may seem a bit wired, so I probably should have provided the real case instead of an abstract example.

I have a function that takes a few arguments, one of them is an object of additional parameters:

```
function setCookie(name, value, {path, domain, expires}) {...}
```

Parameter **expires** was meant to have value of type **Date**, so the JavaScript implementation of that function could just transform this one field on the **options** object into a UTCString, then just take the whole **options** object, parse it and append to the cookie string.

The **options** object except that one field is ready-to-use, so allocating another variable for it just to meet the requirements of TypeScript seemed a little bit annoying.

It looks like there are three ways out, but each of them has its own limitations:

1. "Dirty hack" style.

The first way is to use type casting:

```
type cookieOptions = {
  domain?: string, 
  path? : string,
  expires?: Date
};

function setCookie(name : string, value : string, options : cookieOptions) {
   if ("expires" in options) {
     options.expires = options.expires.toUTCString() as any;  // type casting
   }
   for (let propName in options) {
     updatedCookie += `; ${propName}=${options[propName] as any}`; // type casting
   }
}
```

This concern, firstly, forces us to use type casting twice (while setting the property to the formatted value and while parsing the options object), and secondly, it violates the principle of type-safety, which crushes all benefits from using TypeScript.

2. "Ok I`l handle this" style.

We could just accept formatted string as a possible value of the "expires" param. But that means that we also have to change the implementation.

```
type ExtendedCookieOptions = {
  domain?: string, 
  path? : string,
  expires?: string | Date
};

function setCookie(name : string, value : string, options : ExtendedCookieOptions) {...}
```

3. "Ok, let`s allocate a variable and use it" style described by [Lodewijk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41645100/6465846).

   function setCookie(name : string, value : string, options : cookieOptions) {
     let params : {[index: string] : string} = options as any; // after that, we forget about the "options" variable and use "params" instead
   }

Again, here we have to perform an operation that seems absolutely useless in JavaScript, just to meet the requirements of TypeScript, and that`s why I didn`t want to add a variable, but in this case it seems to be the best way out.

Comment: Your last requirement violates type safety: The caller of this function will *still* have an object typed as `{[index: string]: number}` after the function returns, which is wrong because the values are actually strings. (There's no way to say that the type of a function parameter has changed after invoking the function.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the type `[index: string]: number | string` (as Louis suggested before), but that would also imply you could mix numbers and types in your object, while you might want to have either the one or the other without mixing.

Here is how you could achieve that additional piece of type-safety without allocating another variable.

```
function myStringifier(object: {[index: string]: number}): {[index: string]: string} {
  let result: {[index: string]: string} = <any> object;
  for (let key in object) {
    result[key] = object[key].toString();
  }
  return result;
}
```

To be clear `result` is not an additional variable that is "allocated", because `result` will end up on the stack, which is pre-allocated memory.

Answer (score 2):

You could perform a cast in your assignment:

```
function myStringifier(object: { [index: string]: number}): void {
  for (let key in object) {
    object[key] = object[key].toString() as any; // Cast to any here.
  }
}
```

This does not require any additional variable.

Comment: I liked your previous answer better, because this way you get an object that TypeScript thinks has numbers, but actually has strings, which is just another way to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: Well, the OP edited the question to explicitly reject my initial solution. Given the requirements of the OP the original object **will** have to be modified in a way that makes the TypeScript type declaration a lie. Your solution has the advantage of providing a return value that reflects the new type, but it goes against the OP's requirement that there be no additional variables. The more I think about it, the more I find the requirements rather arbitrary.

Comment: My solution does not have an additional variable. `result` is a pointer to `object` on the stack.

Comment: The requirement does sound arbitrary, although in some js frameworks it is a specific requirement to mutate objects instead of produce new ones.

Comment: @LodewijkBogaards Your solution does have an additional variable. `result` is an additional variable. It does not matter if it is held in the stack:  it is still a variable. It does not matter if it is a pointer: it is still a variable.

Comment: Man, what is this? Code golf? What other silly requirements will you honor: to type the solution with one finger and not use the letter 'f'? I am assuming the point is he does not want to waste memory or is forced by some  framework to mutate.

Answer (score 0):

> P.S.: setting the type of the object argument to:
>
> {[index: string]: number | string}
>   - is not the way out either. I want to be sure that that the argument passed is an object of numbers.

The object you're passing in isn't an object of numbers if you immediately mutate that same object into an object of strings. It's an object of either numbers or strings. This is the wrong place to enforce that your object has numerical keys - you should be doing that when you initially create the object.

For what it's worth, the way I would type the variable would be like this: `{ [index: string]: number } | { [index: string]: string }`. Now you know it's either all `number`s or all `string`s.

Comment: While the type might be a bit more informative, this is not much better then actually just using `number | string` for the object's items, because if you dereference an item from that type of object it will still end up being `number | string`. You would end up having to use a type guard either on the object or on each of its items, which is completely unnecessary if you would just transform the type when the object was transformed.